# How would one use dplyr to recursively concatenate characters in a tibble until a character repeats

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to use dplyr to concatenate characters from prior tibble rows until a character repeats. Once a character repeats, we use the repeated character to start the same concatenation process again. Here is a reprex that shows the source data frame (df) my failed attempt to concatenate the characters (df1) and the desired result of the proposed concatenation process (df2).

In my attempt, it appears the concatenation process only takes place once when we create bf. Unfortunately, I'm not sure why this is the case. I'm still fairly new to dplyr, so I suspect I missing something very obvious. Also, if there is a better approach to solving this problem, I am happy to expand my horizon and knowledge.

```
library (tidyverse)

df <- tibble(id = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14),
             cde =c("b","f","c","e","b","f","c","e","d","f","b","c","e","d"))

df
#> # A tibble: 14 x 2
#>       id cde  
#>    <dbl> <chr>
#>  1     1 b    
#>  2     2 f    
#>  3     3 c    
#>  4     4 e    
#>  5     5 b       
#>  6     6 f    
#>  7     7 c    
#>  8     8 e    
#>  9     9 d    
#> 10    10 f    
#> 11    11 b    
#> 12    12 c    
#> 13    13 e    
#> 14    14 d

df1 <- df %>% 
  mutate(cum_cde = "") %>% 
  mutate(cum_cde = if_else(id ==1,cde,cum_cde)) %>% 
  mutate(cum_cde = if_else(id > 1 & str_count(lag(cum_cde),(cde)) < 1,str_c(lag(cum_cde),cde,sep="",collapse=NULL),cde))

df1
#> # A tibble: 14 x 3
#>       id cde   cum_cde
#>    <dbl> <chr> <chr>  
#>  1     1 b     b      
#>  2     2 f     bf     
#>  3     3 c     c      
#>  4     4 e     e      
#>  5     5 b     b      
#>  6     6 f     f      
#>  7     7 c     c      
#>  8     8 e     e      
#>  9     9 d     d      
#> 10    10 f     f      
#> 11    11 b     b      
#> 12    12 c     c      
#> 13    13 e     e      
#> 14    14 d     d



df2 <- tibble(id = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14),
             cde =c("b","f","c","e","b","f","c","e","d","f","b","c","e","d"),
             result = c("b","bf","bfc","bfce","b","bf","bfc","bfce","bfced","f","fb","fbc","fbce","fbced"))

df2
#> # A tibble: 14 x 3
#>       id cde   result
#>    <dbl> <chr> <chr> 
#>  1     1 b     b     
#>  2     2 f     bf    
#>  3     3 c     bfc   
#>  4     4 e     bfce  
#>  5     5 b     b     
#>  6     6 f     bf    
#>  7     7 c     bfc   
#>  8     8 e     bfce  
#>  9     9 d     bfced 
#> 10    10 f     f     
#> 11    11 b     fb    
#> 12    12 c     fbc   
#> 13    13 e     fbce  
#> 14    14 d     fbced


<sup>Created on 2019-12-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>
```

Comment: OP means "repeats in the concatenation"

Comment: @akrun when I say repeat, I mean in the preceding concatenated string.  b in position 5 is the first repeat as b was the first letter in the initial concatenation. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option with `for` loop would be

```
library(stringr)
v1 <- character(nrow(df))
j <- 1
for(i in seq_len(nrow(df))) {
               v1[i] <- paste(df$cde[unique(j:i)], collapse="")
     if(str_count(v1[i], df$cde[i]) > 1) {
             v1[i] <- df$cde[i]
  j <- i
       }
   }

v1
#[1] "b"     "bf"    "bfc"   "bfce" 
#[5] "b"     "bf"    "bfc"   "bfce"  "bfced" 
#[10]"f"     "fb"    "fbc"   "fbce"  "fbced"
```

---

Or using `accumulate`

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   group_by(grp = cummax(str_count(accumulate(cde, str_c), cde))) %>% 
   mutate(result = accumulate(cde, str_c)) %>%
   ungroup %>% 
   select(-grp)
# A tibble: 14 x 3
#      id cde   result
#   <dbl> <chr> <chr> 
# 1     1 b     b     
# 2     2 f     bf    
# 3     3 c     bfc   
# 4     4 e     bfce  
# 5     5 b     b     
# 6     6 f     bf    
# 7     7 c     bfc   
# 8     8 e     bfce  
# 9     9 d     bfced 
#10    10 f     f     
#11    11 b     fb    
#12    12 c     fbc   
#13    13 e     fbce  
#14    14 d     fbced
```

Comment: thanks for the response. I did even think about a for loop.  Do you have any idea why my dplyr version is failing?